# How to regex match?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following line:

```
mystr = "1A) Monkey Hoop Jumping (MHJ) and Ring Toss (.50 Cents [YEAR2010]; .25 Cents [YEAR2016]) - The performance is estimated to be cheaper (MHJ;)"
mygroups = re.match('<match expression>', mystr)
```

How can I write a match expression in python "re" to get the following groups?

```
line = "1A"
activity = "Monkey Hoop Jumping (MHJ) and Ring Toss"
costin2010 = ".50"
```

I tried the following and it does not work:

```
(?P<line>.+?)\) (?P<activity>.*?) \((?P<costin2010>[\d.]+ Cents [YEAR2010].*?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I could see:

- You were capturing more than you should in `costin2010`
- You did not escape the square bracket

This works:

```
(?P<line>.+?)\) (?P<activity>.*?) \((?P<costin2010>[\d.]+) Cents \[YEAR2010]
```